# How to create a C# regex to accept only these characters?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

How can I create Regex in c# which accept only this characters?

```
    a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
â Â ä Ä á à À Á
é è ê ë Ê È É Ê Ë
- ' ( ) ß 
ñ Ñ Ç ç
Ì Í ì í î ï Î Ï
ò ó ô ö Ó Ô Ö Õ
ù ú û ü Ù Ú Û Ü
```

I try this regex but i don't think is correct:

```
"[-')(a-zA-ZâÂäÄáàÀÁéèêëÊÈÉÊËßñÑÇçÌÍìíîïÎÏòóôöÓÔÖÕùúûüÙÚÛÜ]*"
```

In my unit test, this value **last-'()Name** not match a regex

Comment: Have you made any attempt at this yourself?

Comment: Use a character class?

Comment: [The 30 Minute Regex Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial)

Comment: I'm no regex expert but this looks basic, a quick search on Google could have found thousand of results I'm sure.

Comment: I try the regex "[a-zA-ZâÂäÄáàÀÁéèêëÊÈÉÊË-')(ßñÑÇçÌÍìíîïÎÏòóôöÓÔÖÕùúûüÙÚÛÜ]*"                                                                 but i have this error parsing "[a-zA-ZâÂäÄáàÀÁéèêëÊÈÉÊË-')(ßñÑÇçÌÍìíîïÎÏòóôöÓÔÖÕùúûüÙÚÛÜ]*" - [x-y] range in reverse order.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Could you provide youc C# code? It may be related to escaping - sign. Try escaping it.

Comment: !(Regex.IsMatch("last-'()Name","[a-zA-ZâÂäÄáàÀÁéèêëÊÈÉÊË-')(ßñÑÇçÌÍìíîïÎÏòóôöÓÔÖÕùúûüÙÚÛÜ]*))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that:

```
"[-a-zA-ZâÂäÄáàÀÁéèêëÊÈÉÊË')(ßñÑÇçÌÍìíîïÎÏòóôöÓÔÖÕùúûüÙÚÛÜ]*"
```

Comment: For clarity's sake: within a character class (delimited by `[` and `]`), you don't need to escape special characters like `(`, `)`, `.`, etc.

Comment: I try this regex pas I have an error parsing "[a-zA-ZâÂäÄáàÀÁéèêëÊÈÉÊË-')(ßñÑÇçÌÍìíîïÎÏòóôöÓÔÖÕùúûüÙÚÛÜ]*" - [x-y] range in reverse order.

Comment: @user1428798, the problem is the range `Ë-' ` in your character class. `-` is a special character in a character class and needs to be escaped or at the start or the end of the class, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really want exactly those letters or is the real question "Allow only letters and "- ' ( )" ?

Take a look at [Unicode properties](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop) and [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
[\p{L}'()-]+
```

`\p{L}` is matching any letter in any language

`+` is a quantifier that repeats the previous element 1 or more times

Answer (score 0):

You can use sth like this:

```
[\p{L}()-]+
```